# Ubuntu gawk copy first line without modification

Tags: ubuntu, awk, gawk

I have the following script to add some additional values to CSV file.

The first line in the file are headers, so obviously we want to keep them, but my script skips them at all.

In short, I want to copy everything to the final file, but modify only after first line.

```
gawk -v exists="false" -v app_name="app_name" -v find_date=$(date +%F) -F"[ \t]+" 'BEGIN {OFS = "\t"} NR>1 {$12=exists;$13=app_name;$14=find_date; print}' output.csv > output_final.csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script skips the first line because you told it to work only for lines where `NR>1`. You need to specify what to do when `NR==1`.

```
gawk -v exists="false" -v app_name="app_name" -v find_date=$(date +%F) -F"[ \t]+" '
   BEGIN {OFS = "\t"}
   NR==1 {print}
   NR>1 {$12=exists;$13=app_name;$14=find_date; print}
' output.csv > output_final.csv
```